# using same ActionLink call two function master and details in same Controller c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am new in MVC5. I am trying to load master and details data using ActionResult for retrieving  master data and JsonResult for Details retrieving   data single click in ActionLink.

```
public JsonResult getOrderDetails(int? id)
{
    List<OrderDetail> OrderDetail = new List<OrderDetail>();

    OrderDetail = db.OrderDetails.Where(a => a.OrderID==id).OrderBy(a => a.OrderDetialsID).ToList();

    return new JsonResult { Data = OrderDetail, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}

public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    OrderMaster OrderMaster = db.OrderMasters.Find(id);

    return View(OrderMaster);
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more of what you want to do. This looks like an XY problem which probably can be handled differently.

Comment: i want to load master and details data but using two type of action like ActionResult and JsonResult by clicking   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "getOrderDetails", new { id = item.OrderID },new { id = item.OrderID})

Comment: But *why*? What is the requirement for this? What is the end result? Why isn't the page doing an AJAX query for defails? Why don't you include the details in the object given to the master view? Why do you need these two calls?

Comment: i don't know how to retrieve for edit using AJAX so that trying to this way. Please can you help me?

Comment: Then give the data to the view like you give the OrderMaster now. Make an object that contains both OrderMaster and OrderDetail and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work. It will throw an exception explaining that a link must point to exactly one resource (a.k.a one Controller, one Action). Also, that's not how you normally think of doing it in MVC. This is not WebForms where you load the master and detail separately.

You should be doing something like this instead:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var orderMaster = db.OrderMasters
        .Where(om => om.OrderMasterId == id)
        .Include(om => om.OrderDetails) // include the details here
        .Single();

    return View(orderMaster);
}
```